# why do i get Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. when I'm trying to register?

Tags: python, django, web

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def register(response):
    if response.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreationForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(response, 'register/register.html', {'form':form})
```

html

```
{% extends 'libraryfinish/base.html' %}

{% block title %}
Create an account
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <form method="POST", class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form}}
        <button type="submit", class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

I found that I should pass the RequestContext in my render_to_response for the context processors to actually be run, but I'm not using render to response

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect

@csrf_protect
doesn't work

Comment: What is the value of `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS` setting?

Answer (score 0):

you have to add your localhost into the **CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS** list in your settings.py file like this,

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ['127.0.0.1', 'localhost']
```